# Android Studio add user input from dialog to previous value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog, android-alertdialog

currently I am creating an App that is supposed to track your habits. My Main Activity has a Dialog where you choose, what you want to track. After that another Dialog shows depending on which option you clicked.
I have an edittext in the WaterTracking dialog, where the user can input the amount of water they have been drinking. on positiveButton.Clicked, the user input is suppose to be added to the total.
I am pretty clueless on how I am supposed to implement the counter, where the prevwater and the inputwater from he edittext is calculated to the total.

For example, starting with 0 mililiters, the user types 200 into the edittext, and the total would be 200 mililiters.
At the next input, for example 300, the program is supposed to add the previous to the new, 200 + 300 = 500.
And so on, that 500 + ... = total

I thought of having 3 variables: totalwater, inputwater and prevwater.

totalwater = prevwaer + inputwater

prevwater has value of totalwater

I don't really have code to show, because I have been clueless. Also I am pretty new to Java. Maybe I am missing something.

How would you solve this considering the dialogs and the variable saving the previous input?

Answer (score 0):

Create local db. store the edit text input. add new rows for each input. add the values of all rows and show as total. For creating local db check this link https://github.com/PM1509/SqliteSample